# stl c++ error: unable to open vector headerfile, ";" expected

Tags: c++, vector

I searched a lot to clear the following error, couldn't find the answer.
I am getting the following errors. pls someone help me thanks in advance

```
ERROR: unable to open vector headerfile, 
";" expected
```

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class MyQueue
{
std::vector<T> data;
public:
void Add(T const &);
void Remove();
void Print();
};

template <typename T> void MyQueue<T> ::Add(T const &d)
{
data.push_back(d);
}

template <typename T> void MyQueue<T>::Remove()
{
data.erase(data.begin( ) + 0,data.begin( ) + 1);
}

template <typename T> void MyQueue<T>::Print()
{
std::vector <int>::iterator It1;
It1 = data.begin();
for ( It1 = data.begin( ) ; It1 != data.end( ) ; It1++ )
cout << " " << *It1<<endl;

}
//Usage for C++ class templates
void main()
{
MyQueue<int> q;
q.Add(1);
q.Add(2);

cout<<"Before removing data"<<endl;
q.Print();

q.Remove();
cout<<"After removing data"<<endl;
q.Print();
}
```

Comment: Where is the compiler looking for the headers?  There is some kind of global setting to point to the correct path, and maybe that is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
#include <iostream.h>
```

to

```
#include <iostream>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its

```
#include <iostream> not <iostream.h>.
```

Didn't you get any error like "Cannot open include file: 'iostream.h': No such file or directory".